# Additional class for loading async requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a React app and I noticed I am using one function more than twice. So I decided to extract it and make a new class of it. It looks like this:

```
export default class Fetcher {
  constructor(url, callback) {
    this.url = url;
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  getData() {
    const url = '/wp-json/wp/v2/' + this.url;
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.open('get', url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if(req.readyState === 4) {
        if(req.status === 200) {
          this.callback();
          return req.responseText;
        } else {
          throw new Error();
        }
      }
    }
    req.send();
  }
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```
  import Fetcher from '../Tools/XML';
  fetchPost() {
    const data = new Fetcher('posts?slug='+this.props.params.slug, this.renderPost);
    console.log(data.getData());
  }
```

My problem is, `console.log` returns `undefined`. I understand this happens because the requests are asynchronous and the rendering is finished before the query can be done.

My question is, how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the callback, as you can't have direct return value when working asynchronously.

In `getData()` method, change this line:

```
this.callback();
```

To this:

```
this.callback(req.responseText);
```

Then put the console.log in the callback function:

```
renderPost(responseText) {
    console.log(responseText);
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Comment: @TomekBuszewski Cheers, not familiar with react.js but familiar with asynchronous JavaScript due to node.js and AngularJS. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `XMLHttpRequest` API uses same named constructor to make asynchronous calls as per MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#XMLHttpRequest.

In your scenario, you are using this api, but the api cannot return any data directly to caller as `getData()` returns nothing to its caller, being an asynchronous method. 
Since, you have a `callback()`, use it to pass the result of the asynchronous call back to its caller using

```
this.callback(req.responseText);
```

So once the method completes, the callback will be passed the `responseText` as argument. In order to handle that change the method signature for the callback to accept this argument as:

```
renderPost (responseText) {
  // Use the response now 
  console.log(responseText);
}
```